# Does Ubuntu 10.10 have the same Intel i915GM problems as 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu, intel-graphics

I'm referring to [this issue](http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2010/05/06/ubuntu-10-04-lucid-blank-screen-at-startup-workaround/)

I guess I can just download the beta image and try it out, but I have limited bandwidth and would prefer to conserve what little I have left....

Basically, I could not get 10.04 to work as reliably as 9.10 on my HP Pavillion as it uses Intel i915GM, despite trying out all the suggested workarounds, and so i've been stuck on 9.10 but would love to upgrade to 10.10 in order to take advantage of the many new features...

Do any of you who had the same problems with 10.04 know if they have cleared up in 10.10?

Answer (score 1):

10.10 is much, much worse.  X won't even start after installing 10.10 and I only get about 30 seconds to try to check the logs before the whole system dies.  I'd save my bandwidth if I were you.

Comment: thanks, i think i'll stick with 9.10 for a while longer, it's not so bad

Answer (score 1):

I have a few HP machines with onboard intel video chips.  For the most part, Ubuntu 10.10 worked great from the start (installed on October 10th).  Here is a list of my results:

HP 6910p - Worked OK with 9.10, 10.04, 10.10.

HP EliteBook 6930p -  Worked OK with 9.10, 10.04 and 10.10.

HP Tablet 2730p - Worked OK with 9.10, didn't try 10.04, does NOT work with 10.10.  The screen is pitch black.

HP DC7800 - Worked OK with 9.10, didn't try 10.04, works OK with 10.10.

HP tablet 2740p - Worked somehow under 9.10 (frequent freezes), did NOT work under 10.04 (screen is pitch black), works perfectly under 10.10.

As for the one the one that doesn't work under 10.10, my HP tablet 2730p, I have to say that none of the workarounds provided work.

My suggestion would be to wait, give it a couple months before you make a move.

Good Luck

Comment: thankyou very much.  i will take your advice and stick with what i have for now

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from 10.04 to 10.10. Display is black if you boot with the kernel version 2.6.35.
I boot with a 2.6.32 version and all is ok.